# Servlet no ejecuta forward

Tags: java, jsp

Buen día.
Estoy volviendo a realizar un proyecto que lo hice hace tiempo con NetBeans 8.2 y JDK 1.8, donde por cierto funciona bien; pero ahora lo estoy haciendo con Apache Netbeans IDE 14 y JDK 17.

El problema que tengo es que en mi Servlet tengo un método llamado **listar** el cual se conecta a la DB para poder listar los elementos de una tabla a través de una vista(Enviárselo a un JSP), entonces cuando realizo la ejecución del Servlet individualmente lo que me muestra es:

**Está página no funciona**
La página **localhost** no puede procesar esta solicitud ahora.
HTTP ERROR 500
Crei que era porque el Servidor Glassfish no estaba funcionando pero descarte ello, entonces pensé que el Servlet lo habia hecho mal por lo que cree un nuevo Servlet de prueba y al ejecutarlo manualmente ejecuta sin problema, entonces el problema debe estar en el código y haciendo ensayo y error comentando las líneas de código me percate que la última línea es la que me da precisamente ese error, ya que si esta la comento se ejecuta normal está línea es:
**rd.forward(request, response);**
Para que se entienda mejor voy a poner el código del Servlet y del JSP
Código del Servlet

---------------

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/JSP_Servlet/Servlet.java to edit this template
 */
package uni.sistemas.controller;

import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.List;

import uni.sistemas.entity.Producto;
import uni.sistemas.model.ProductoDao;


public class ProductoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //Obtenemos el alias del Servlet
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        try{
            switch (path) {
                case "/Listar":
                    listar(request,response);
                    break;
                case "/Adicionar":
                    adicionar(request,response);
                    break;
                case "/Modificar":
                    actualizar(request,response);
                    break;
                case "/Eliminar":
                    eliminar(request,response);
                    break;
                case "/Consultar":
                    consultar(request,response);
                    break;
            }
            
        } catch(IOException | ServletException e){
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private void listar(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException{
        String destino=null;
        try{
           ProductoDao dao = new ProductoDao();
           List<Producto> lista = dao.readAll();
           request.setAttribute("lista", lista);
           destino="productolistar.jsp";
        }catch(Exception e){
         request.setAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
         destino="productolistar.jsp";
        }
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(destino);
        rd.forward(request, response);
        
        
    }
    
    

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try ( PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet ProductoServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet ProductoServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Código del JSP
----------

```
<%-- 
    Document   : productolistar
    Created on : 17 abr. 2023, 14:00:54
    Author     : vsilvaf
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Listado de Productos</h1>
        
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="5">Productos listados</th>
                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Código</td>
                    <td>Descripción</td>
                    <td>IdLínea</td>
                    <td>Precio</td>
                    <td>Stock</td>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach var="pro" items="${requestScope.lista}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${pro.idproducto}</td>
                    <td>${pro.descripcion}</td>
                    <td>${pro.idlinea}</td>
                    <td>${pro.precioventa}</td>
                    <td>${pro.stock}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        
    </body>
</html>
```

Quiza me no estoy colocando alguna información que alguien considere para poder dar con la solución, de ser así, me la puede solicitar para brindársela.
**Me olvide comentarles que el proyecto fue creado en Apache Netbeans como: Java with Maven-->Web Application**
**El jsp lo ejecuto individualmente sin problema**
Agradeciendoles por el apoyo me despido.